# Google Maps API with loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using a loop to add markers to a Google Map. The loop did work before I implemented the if-statements. Why wont it work now? I just dont understand why it wont work, it seems logical?

```
for(int i=1;i<statoilnumber;i++) {
    String XCord = sharedPreferences.getString("XCord"+i,"0");

    String YCord = sharedPreferences.getString("YCord"+i, "0");
    int Title = sharedPreferences.getInt("Title" + i, 0);
    String Info = sharedPreferences.getString("Info" + i, "0");
    String Icon = sharedPreferences.getString("Icon" + i, "4");
    String realTitle = Integer.toString(Title);
    // Drawing marker on the map

    if(Icon=="4") {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YCord), Double.parseDouble(XCord)))
                                            .title(realTitle + ". Statoil")
                                            .snippet(Info)
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.statoil_correct)));
    }
    if(Icon=="1") {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YCord), Double.parseDouble(XCord)))
                            .title(realTitle + ". Statoil")
                            .snippet(Info)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.approved_scale)));
    }
    if(Icon=="2") {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YCord), Double.parseDouble(XCord)))
                            .title(realTitle + ". Statoil")
                            .snippet(Info)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.clock_scale)));
    }
    if(Icon=="3") {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(YCord), Double.parseDouble(XCord)))
                            .title(realTitle + ". Statoil")
                            .snippet(Info)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.death_scale)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Define doesn't work... does it throw exceptions? does it draw things multiple times? does it always draw the "Icon==4" option?.  You should really be doing either a switch or a if/else (and in either case, include a default option if Icon doesn't match any of your values)

Comment: Icon is a String, use `(Icon.equals("4"))`  and so on.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant compare String with == sysmbol

you need to use `Icon.equels("second string")`

> == symbol compares Object ref. not actual data